# Failed password verification in own login class

Tags: php, authentication

i am currently working on my own user class with login and register functions. I am doing this mainly for the learing experience. Now i am having a problem wich i am unable to resolve.
My register function looks like this:

```
public function createUser($username, $email, $password)
{   
    $password = trim($password);
//Generate users salt
$user_salt = $this->getRandomHash();

//Salt and Hash the password
$password = $user_salt . $password;
$password = $this->hashData($password);

//Create verification code
$code = $this->randomString();

//Commit values to database here.
$created = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password, user_salt, is_verified, is_active, verification_code) VALUES ('".$username."','".$email."', '".$password."', '".$user_salt."', 0, 1, '".$code."')";
    $created = $this->_database->Set($created);

if($created != false){
    return true;
}

return false;
}
```

while hashData looks like this:

```
protected function hashData($data)
{
return hash_hmac('sha512', $data, $this->_siteKey);
}
```

and this is my login function:

```
$password = trim($password);
//Select users row from database base on $email
$selection = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$username."' LIMIT 1";
    $selection = $this->_database->Get($selection);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selection);
    //Salt and hash password for checking
    $password = $row['user_salt'] . $password;
    $password = $this->hashData($password);

    $match = false;
    //Check email and password hash match database row
    if($username == $row['username'] && $password == $row['password']){
       $match = true;
    }
```

Now the problem is that the passwords do not match even though i am hundret percent sure im typing it correctly. I am not quite sure why it fails because i am using the same salt to hash the typed in password. Maybe i am doing something completly wrong here...If you need more code please let me know. Otherwise thanks to anyone willing to help.

Comment: You should try printing `$salt . $password` during the initial hashing, and when you get it out of the database. Also, `hash_hmac` doesn't look like it does multiple iterations, so your hashing is insecure.

Comment: the "$salt . $password" is exactly the same before putting it into the database and after reading it from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupid mistake on my part!

The salt column in the database was only accepting a salt with the length of 50. My generated salt was way longer..